# Почему в WordPress теме не подключается Roboto Slab?

Tags: wordpress

Open Sans вроде подключается, но Roboto Slab никак не хочет. Вместо него подключается стандартный с засечками. Помогите разобраться, что не так в коде.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_child_fonts' ) ) :
    /**
     * Create fonts url and enqueue fonts.
     */
    function theme_fonts() {
        /**
         * Create fonts url.
         *
         * @return string $fonts_url
         */
        function theme_fonts_url() {

            $fonts_url = '';
            /*
             * Translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported by font below, translate this to 'off'.
             * Do not translate into your own language.
             */
            $font_1 = _x( 'on', 'Roboto Slab font: on or off', 'theme' );
            /*
             * Translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported by font below, translate this to 'off'.
             * Do not translate into your own language.
             */
            $font_2 = _x( 'on', 'Open Sans font: on or off', 'theme' );

            if ( 'off' !== $font_1 || 'off' !== $font_2 ) {

                $font_families = array();

                if ( 'off' !== $font_1 ) {
                    $font_families[] = 'Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700';
                }

                if ( 'off' !== $font_2 ) {
                    $font_families[] = 'Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i';
                }

                $query_args = array(
                    'family' => rawurlencode( implode( '|', $font_families ) ),
                    'subset' => rawurlencode( 'cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext' ),
                );

                $fonts_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, '//fonts.googleapis.com/css' );
            }

            return esc_url_raw( $fonts_url );
        }
        /**
         * Enqueue fonts.
         */
        function theme_enqueue_fonts() {
            /*
             * Load fonts.
             */
            wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_fonts', theme_fonts_url(), array(), null );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_fonts' );
    }
endif;
```

Comment: Где вы взяли это кусок кода? Обёртка не связана с содержимым, одна функция не связана со второй, вложенные функции - что вообще не работает, да ещё и баланс скобок вроде не соблюден. Этот код не может работать, по крайней мере, на первый взгляд с телефона.

Comment: В интернете на англоязычных сайтах (с некоторой правкой под себя). А как вы подключаете несколько шрифтов в теме? Можете привести код?

Comment: Да так же, как и один. Позже покажу. Сейчас на телефоне.

Answer (score 3):

Подключить два Google шрифта можно таким образом:

```
/**
 * Register custom fonts.
 */
function my_theme_fonts_url() {
    $fonts_url     = '';
    $font_families = array();

    /*
     * Translators: If there are characters in your language that are not
     * supported by your fonts, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate
     * into your own language.
     */
    $roboto_slab = _x( 'on', 'Roboto Slab font: on or off', 'my_theme' );
    $open_sans   = _x( 'on', 'Open Sans font: on or off', 'my_theme' );

    if ( 'off' !== $roboto_slab ) {
        $font_families[] = 'Roboto Slab:100,300,400,700';
    }

    if ( 'off' !== $open_sans ) {
        $font_families[] = 'Open Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $font_families ) ) {
        $query_args = array(
            'family' => rawurlencode( implode( '|', $font_families ) ),
            'subset' => rawurlencode( 'cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin,latin-ext' ),
        );

        $fonts_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css' );
    }

    return esc_url_raw( $fonts_url );
}

function my_theme_scripts() {
    // Add custom fonts, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-fonts', my_theme_fonts_url(), array(), null );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

Во время события `wp_enqueue_scripts` вызывается функция `my_theme_scripts`. Она запускает стандартную `wp_enqueue_style` с формированием url для нее в `my_theme_fonts_url`.

Вот эти игрушки с _x можно выкинуть, но они используются очень часто в темах, в том числе в twentyseventeen, так что пусть остаются.

Сформированный массив $font_families содержит в нашем случае два элемента - для двух шрифтов. обратите внимание - название шрифта надо писать без `+`, с пробелом. Знак `+` подставляет rawurlencode.

С помощью query_args добавляем семейства и subset в строку запроса `$fonts_url` и возвращаем ее как результат работы функции.

Comment: С `subset` есть вопрос. Он ведь разный может быть для разных шрифтов, как Гугл его связывает с нужным семейством? Можно ли теоретически  все `subset` указать и не волноваться ни за какой шрифт?

Comment: Я не увидел способа, как указать в одном URL разные subset для разных шрифтов. Если это очень нужно, придётся делать две похожие функции my_theme_fonts_url и дважды вызывать wp_enqueue_scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была из-за вызова `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts'...` внутри функции, которая сама не вызывалась.

Comment: Вот вы мне объясните - в чем смысл вашего ответа? У вас в вопросе была не одна, а куча ошибок - одна на другой. Я вам все сделал. Теперь вы скопипастили мой ответ, ну добавили третий шрифт, о котором в вопросе не было ни слова. Да еще и оставили вложение функций одна в другую, что не рекомендуется по многим причинам, и на что я вам указал сразу в комментарии.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос. А не давать копипасту моего ответа, как нечто самостоятельное. Мой код рабочий, я его у себя на сайте проверял.

Comment: @KAGG Design, ваш код правильный и действующий, но вы не указали точно причину бездействия моего кода, а мне, в первую очередь, хотелось понять именно это, а не просто получить готовый код. Эта причина мною была выявлена самостоятельно, независимо от вашего ответа. Вложенность функций — вынужденная, для возможности переопределения в дочерней теме.  Мой ответ — не копипаст вашего, а копипаст половины интернета (как и ваш). По сути, ответ на мой вопрос был дан мною же. Но за ваш пример действующего кода вам добавлен балл за полезность и за один конструктивный комментарий также.

Comment: Прочитайте первую фразу моего ответа "Во время события wp_enqueue_scripts вызывается функция my_theme_scripts". Вложенность для переопределения не используют, делают совсем по-другому. Мой ответ - не бездумная копипаста, как у вас, а отлаженный код, да еще и с объяснениями. Баллы свои можете себе назад забрать, у меня их достаточно. Но в следующий раз разгребайте говнокод из вашего вопроса сами.